# GCP Cloud Run deployed Docker container does not start because of nginx image is failing to find error.log

Tags: docker, nginx, google-cloud-run

When I deploy my Vue.js webapp to Cloud Run it does not seems to bootstrap properly. Running the container locally or in a Kubernetes Pod does work as expected.

This is the Dockerfile I am using:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["touch", "/var/log/ngingx/error.log"]
CMD ["touch", "/var/log/ngingx/access.log"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**local docker build log:** https://pastebin.com/1nGk2E5n

**bitbucket pipeline docker build log:** https://pastebin.com/d5wCj1vY

Cloud Run error message (actual docker container start log):

```
Deploying container to Cloud Run for Anthos service [importer-controlroom-frontend-dev] in namespace [dev] of cluster [myApp-cluster-dev]
Deploying...
Creating Revision...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................failed
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision "importer-controlroom-frontend-dev-00003-tum" failed with message: Container failed with: /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2020/07/17 08:26:03 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
.
```

Local docker container deploy log:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

So I have two different outcomes. I somewhat think that Cloud Run handles the nginx differently and I also read some blog articles about that but I just can't find out how I can bring my app to run without this mentioned issue.

Comment: Can  you change set inline the last 3 lines of your dockerfile? Like this `CMD touch /var/log/ngingx/error.log && touch /var/log/ngingx/access.log && nginx -g daemon off;`

Answer (score 0):

My read of the error message(s) is that

1. you need to possibly `mkdir -p /var/log/nginx` before you start nginx (mkdir should **not** be part of your Dockerfile, but as part of your container startup i.e. CMD/ENTRYPOINT). Maybe this directory exists in your container image; but Cloud Run re-mounts a clean volume to /var/log upon startup.
2. Consider not using /var/log/nginx in Cloud Run. Instead, please study nginx images in Docker Hub to see how they print logs to /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr devices.
3. It seems like you don't understand what `CMD`/`ENTRYPOINT` do properly. `CMD cmd1` and `CMD cmd2` isn't doing what you think it does. Please spend the time and read the Docker docs on what these actually do.
4. It seems you have multiple commands upon startup, consider wrapping these in a bash script and set that as your `ENTRYPOINT`. That script would run startup commands, and would finally replace itself with nginx by doing `exec nginx [...]`.
5. You have a typo at `ngingx`.